Paged.js in Vue 3 ignores page-break attempts
I've been attempting to implement page-breaks in Vue.js 3. I've been using the following CSS, it appears that it does work, because I can modify the titlePage for example center/not center it. However the parameter for class ".page-break" seems to ellude me. You can see all my attempts to make it work below. There are no other external CSS imports used. I am using Vue-Showdown for markdown to HTML conversion.
None of the page-break attempts you can see down below actually work and I am super confused on why they are not.
*Note that this does work if I don't send it to PagedJS, like directly a print function
My use case is that I need to uise PagedJS to generate a paginated content to update my TOC with page numbers, which I would print afterwards.
Been tearing my hair out why this isn't working.


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Print Markdown</title>
        <style>
             @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 20mm;
                @bottom-right-corner {
                    vertical-align: center;
                    text-align: center;
                    background: #fafafa;
                    color: purple;
                    content: "P. " counter(page);
                }
            }

            h1 {
                break-before: page;
                page-break-before: always;

            }

            .pagedjs_page {
                break-before: page;
                page-break-before: always;

            }

            @media print {
                h1, h2 {
                    break-before: page;
                    page-break-before: always;

                }
                .page-break {
                    break-before: page;
                    page-break-before: always;

                }
            }

            @media screen {
                h1, h2 {
                    break-before: page;
                    page-break-before: always;

                }
                .page-break {
                    break-before: page;
                    page-break-before: always;

                }
            }

            table, figure {
                page-break-inside: avoid; /* Avoid breaking these elements across pages */
            } 
            
            .title-page {
                break-after: always;
                page-break-before: always;
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 60mm;
            }
            
            .page-break {
                break-before: page;
                page-break-before: always;

            }

            .content-page {
                padding: 15mm 20mm;
            }

            img {
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                display: block;
                margin: 10mm auto;
            } 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title-page">${titleContent}</div>
        <div class="content-page">${restOfContent.innerHTML}</div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>



I tried manipulating the page-breaks using different formats, types, but it doesn't seem to break on anything.

Lately I've been playing with pagedjs in Vue 3 and encountered similar sorts of issues. In case it is helpful for you or other readers of this question here is what I've done.
I'm creating a simple Vue application with an index.html that mounts a single App.vue file in a blank page. In App.vue I'm importing and using Previewer from pagedjs (installed with npm). To run the app I'm using vite. With this setup here are some of my observations.
DOM consistency
One issue is that pagedjs doesn't know about Vue. It will happily modify the DOM of the page in a way that Vue doesn't know about. If you call Previewer.preview and give it a DOM element that Vue has rendered you can quickly get into an inconsistent state. This is a common problem mixing Vue with direct DOM manipulation. My way of solving this is to have a div on the page with a specific id that my code is in charge of rendering. In App.vue there is a watchEffect that fires on changes to data that then calls Previewer.preview to re-render the specific div.
I also needed to clear the output each time, otherwise I would get multiple copies of the output:
element.innerHTML = '';

HMR
The next observation is that vite will use HMR for CSS styles. The HMR system doesn't play well with pagedjs. While rendering pagedjs needs fine-grained control over CSS styling. With HMR the styles will end up applied to the page in a way that the browser will see them but pagedjs will not be able to understand and manipulate them. For me this issue manifested as seeing things like color changes taking effect when I changed the CSS, but having things like @page not work.
My solution to styling is to pass a URL for style information in the second argument to Previewer.preview. To avoid any minification or HMR rewriting from vite I generate the URL like this:
import cssRaw from './book.css?raw';

const cssUrl = URL.createObjectURL((new Blob([cssRaw], { type: 'text/css' })));
paged.preview(htmlContent, [cssUrl], element);

Race Conditions with Polyfill
The final observation is something I noticed with small examples. When I was debugging pagedjs problems I tried making small demo pages that used paged.polyfill.js. I encountered many cases where things would work or not work depending on ordering of script tags and random timing variations on loading assets. My solution to these problems was to turn off pagedjs auto rendering in the configuration:
window.PagedConfig = { auto: false };

I rewrote the examples to call window.PagedPolyfill.preview() instead at the correct time after the DOM was in the right state. That fixed the examples for me. I think the root problem is that PagedPolyfill is waiting for the DOM to load and be ready but it is common for Vue code to do DOM updates after that point.

Wow, thank you so much! I've spent hours trying to get page breaks to work, wondering why sometimes the print to PDF in the browser showed them, other times not, and never in the preview in the page...I couldn't find any pointers anywhere and was about to give up - the vite HMR issue was the problem - you really made my day :D

How to use Vue.js variables in DOM
In Vue.js, you can output variable values between {{ and }} symbols. If you want to output HTML code as well, use the v-html attribute.

Text Interpolation - {{ variable }} - Vue.js Docs
Raw HTML - v-html="..." - Vue.js Docs

You can also declare an existing DOM element as a reactive variable. See in my example the functionality of the copyableElement variable, with which I could pass the content of the first div to the fourth one.

Template ref="..." - Vue.js Docs



const { createApp, ref, reactive } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const titleContent = ref('My Title Content <br>and <strong>can\'t use</strong> HTML elements between {{ and }}');
    const restOfContent = reactive({
      innerHTML: `<strong>My</strong><br>HTML Content`
    });
    
    const copyableElement = ref(null);

    return {
      titleContent,
      restOfContent,
      copyableElement,
    };
  }
}).mount('#app');
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div ref="copyableElement">Example Text What Can Copy<br>To Another Element</div>

  <div class="title-page">titleContent text: {{ titleContent }}</div>
  <div class="content-page" v-html="restOfContent.innerHTML"></div>
  <div class="content-page" v-html="copyableElement?.innerHTML ?? ''"></div>
</div>



How to use Paged.js
The .pagedjs_pages is the CSS class for styling the entire document. Within this, you can use the .pagedjs_page class to style individual pages. If you want to add custom CSS styling to content within such a page, you should add your own class, in our case .myPage, to the divs to be paginated.
If you break the .myPage class, Paged.js will automatically detect it and assign the .pagedjs_page classes accordingly.

Page Breaks - Paged.js Docs

break-before: auto/page; - MDN Docs

break-after: auto/page; - MDN Docs

break-inside: auto/page; - MDN Docs





⚠️ Warning




page-break-before, page-break-after, page-break-inside are deprecated





const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const pages = ref([]);

    // Generate content for pages
    function generateContent() {
      // Simulated content for demonstration
      const content = [
        "<h1>Page 1</h1><p>This is content for page 1.</p>",
        "<h1>Page 2</h1><p>This is content for page 2.</p>",
        "<h1>Page 3</h1><p>This is content for page 3.</p>"
      ];
      pages.value = content;
    }
    generateContent();

    return {
      pages,
    };
  }
});

app.mount('#app');
@page {
  size: A5;
  margin: 20mm;
  @bottom-right-corner {
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fafafa;
    color: purple;
    content: "P. " counter(page);
  }
}

.pagedjs_page {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.myPage {
  break-after: page;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pagedjs/dist/paged.polyfill.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="myPage" v-for="(pageContent, index) in pages" :key="index">
    <div v-html="pageContent"></div>
  </div>
</div>



Example with Fully HTML DOM


const { createApp, ref, reactive } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const content = ref('');
    
    const titleContent = ref('My Title Content');
    const restOfContent = reactive({
      innerHTML: `<strong>My</strong><br>HTML Content`
    });

    // Generate content
    function generateContent() {
      // Simulated content for demonstration
      content.value = `<html>
        <head>
          <title>Print Markdown</title>
          <style>
            /* moved to style of component */
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="title-page">${titleContent.value}</div>
          <div class="content-page">${restOfContent.innerHTML}</div>
          <div class="footer"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
      `;
    }
    generateContent();

    return {
      content,
    };
  }
});

app.mount('#app');
/* just prettier layout */

.pagedjs_page {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

/* original */

@page {
  size: A5; /* changed from A4 */
  margin: 20mm;
  @bottom-right-corner {
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fafafa;
    color: purple;
    content: "P. " counter(page);
  }
}

h1 {
  break-before: page;
  page-break-before: always;
}

.pagedjs_page {
  break-before: page;
  page-break-before: always;
}

@media print {
  h1, h2 {
    break-before: page;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  .page-break {
    break-before: page;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}

@media screen {
  h1, h2 {
    break-before: page;
    page-break-before: always;

  }
  .page-break {
    break-before: page;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}

table, figure {
  page-break-inside: avoid; /* Avoid breaking these elements across pages */
} 

.title-page {
  break-after: always;
  page-break-before: always;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 60mm;
}

.page-break {
  break-before: page;
  page-break-before: always;
}

.content-page {
  padding: 15mm 20mm;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 10mm auto;
} 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pagedjs/dist/paged.polyfill.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-html="content"></div>
</div>




Damn, the quality and details of that answer man!

Thank you for the answer, it is amazing overall. The admins did mess up my initial question with edits, the initial question was that I had a full HTML DOM, starting from  and ending with  all the /
@RaimondsLiepiņš I added an example to my answer where I pass an entire HTML DOM as content. In this case, you cannot enforce the <style> attribute, the explanation of which you can find here: CSS styles not being applied to HTML within v-html.

Since you didn't provide a reproduction similar to what's visible in my answer, I can't be sure of what exactly you wrote in the Vue code. What seems to be your issue, so far, I can only provide working examples and explanations. Based on what I've seen, I thought it might be worth discussing use cases for Vue variables and CSS page break settings. Additionally, new information has emerged regarding declaring the <style> attribute within a Vue component in v-html.

In my Vue code I have the code below that's relevant for passing the HTML code. I essentially need to render the pages in order to get their count and object location in those pages like Heading 1, Heading 2, because this is much easier and consistent than when doing the calculation yourself. contentHTML = 
paged.preview(contentHTML, [], targetContainer).then((flow) => {
console.log('Rendered', flow.total, 'pages.');....

@rozsazoltan your answer I believe is very good and is going to be helpful for a lot of visitors it's just that it doesn't help in any way to solve my actual problem, which is page-breaks in CSS not getting respected when doing pagedjs preview.

If you pass CSS in v-html for rendering, as I mentioned, no CSS setting will be valid. If possible, CSS should already be injected into the original head.

The thing is that when I use paged.preview the CSS settings are valid, for example the .title-page settings apply correctly like center and padding-top. The only thing that is missing are the page breaks, when I send the exact same content directly to print it will respect them. My goal is not to render any content for HTML, but rather preview that content as in print, detect the page count and generate a Table of Contents for that content.
